# comparing svycoxph models with likelihood ratio test

Tags: r, survey, cox-regression

To find the optimal multivariate-adjusted Cox model (svycoxph) I'd like to compare different models with a likelihood ratio test to learn which model is better. Comparing to models with anova(model1, model2) or AIC doesn't work with survey weighted cox models ('No anova method for survey models', 'No AIC for survey models'). Does anyone have an idea how I can compare two svycoxph models?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`anova` now does work with `svycoxph`; it implements the Rao-Scott-type working likelihood ratio tests.